# How do a make a precipitation histogram binned by month?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram of precipitation data for a certain location. I've successfully made a line plot of the data, but I'm a bit stuck on 1) how to make a histogram with this data and 2) how to make the histogram binned by months. When I print precip, it looks like this (shortened version for example):

```
[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.92255229e-01 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 1.50845976e+01 4.94040642e+01 1.09846497e+01
 2.97186822e-02 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 5.66242523e-02]
```

and the shape of precip is (366,).
The matplotlib line plot of the data looks like this:

[image: Precipitation line plot]

I've indexed the original data to be for one lat/lon point, but this is info for the non-indexed data:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'precip' (time: 366, lat: 120, lon: 300)>
[13176000 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 20.12 20.38 20.62 20.88 ... 49.12 49.38 49.62 49.88
  * lon      (lon) float32 230.1 230.4 230.6 230.9 ... 304.1 304.4 304.6 304.9
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 ... 2020-12-31
Attributes:
    long_name:     Daily Accumulated Precipitation
    valid_range:   [  0. 700.]
    units:         mm
    precision:     2
    var_desc:      Precipitation
    dataset:       CPC Unified Gauge-Based Analysis of Daily Precipitation ov...
    level_desc:    Surface
    statistic:     Daily Accumulation
    parent_stat:   Observation
    actual_range:  [  0.      274.80292]
```

Comment: you can make a histogram using xarray with `da.plot.hist()`. what do you mean when you say you want to do this by month? do you want 12 subplots, with a histogram in each? or do you want a histogram of the monthly totals?

Comment: I was going for monthly totals. I should specify that the indexed data is currently a numpy array, so I can't use xarray.

Comment: Why did you paste an xarray DataArray and use the xarray tag then? You know you can select one point using xarray, so you don’t have to go to numpy?

Comment: I added the [tag:python-xarray] tag, so that part's on me. I saw the xarray sample and figured that's what they were using.

Comment: Ok. If you’re starting from xarray though I recommend that you do make use of the xarray plotting and selection features rather than trying to go from xarray to numpy to pandas. If you have a question about how to select data feel free to ask!

Answer (score 3):

You can create monthly summary stats with resample:

```py
monthly_total = da.resample(time="MS").sum()
```

You can then plot a histogram:

```py
monthly_total.plot.hist()
```

Or alternatively a time series bar chart:

```py
monthly_total.plot.bar()
```

See the xarray docs on [resampling](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/time-series.html#resampling-and-grouped-operations) and [plotting](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/plotting.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Is this along the lines of what you're attempting to do?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#generating some data
dates = pd.date_range(start = "2015", end = "2016", freq = "7D")
precip = np.random.rand(len(dates))

df = pd.DataFrame({"dates":dates, "precipitation":precip})
df["month"] = df["dates"].dt.month

df.groupby(by = "month", as_index = True).agg({"precipitation":sum}).plot(kind = "bar")
```

Comment: I think so! The only problem I come across with that is I have no idea how to get the dates in the "dates":dates part. Obviously the dates exist as they're being plotted automatically in the line plot. I just don't know what I need to type for the histogram to work

Comment: Can you produce a small exemplar of the data you are working with in your question? (i.e., generate some data that looks like the data you're working with)

Comment: The data I'm using is from here: https://psl.noaa.gov/mddb2/showDataset.html?datasetID=45. The only thing about it I changed was indexing the data to be at one lat/lon location. It should just be one year of daily precipitation for the location.

Comment: So I've got it to plot a basic histogram, but the axes are wrong. It has the days on the y-axis and precipitation on the x-axis.